# How can I detect the position and the radius of the ball using opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to detect this ball: [image: please click here] and find its position and radius using opencv. I have downloaded many codes, but neither of them works. Any helps are highly appreciated.

Comment: If you are doing something serious with that equipment, make life easy for yourself and do some experiments with different lighting (that doesn't cause shadows) and maybe painting the ball a different colour (or a checkerboard pattern) and the background a contrasting colour first - it will simplify your image processing.

Comment: please clarify the problem. Is the ball moving? If yes, how is it moving? speed is needed. Is the image like the attached one or maybe it is better and bigger with less shadow? If you could take a larger image so that the picture is larger, you could use gradient of the ball surface to find the position of the ball relative to the camera(you need to know the radius which you don't have)!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and reply. I only need to find the 2-D (not 3-D) position and radius of ball in the picture attached. If you have time, you can download the image and help me testing it using opencv. I am a newer (image processing is completely strange to me). Thanks any way.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have quite a setup installed. As mentioned in the comments, please make sure that you have appropriate lighting to capture the ball, as well as making the ball distinguishable from it's surroundings by painting it a different colour.

Once your setup is optimized for detection, you may proceed via different ways to track your ball (stationary or not). A few ways may be:

1. Feature detection : Via Hough Circles, detect 2D circles (and their radius) that lie within a certain range of color, as explained below

There are many more ways to detect objects via feature detection, such as [this clever blog](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/) points out.

2. Object Detection: Via SURF, SIFT and many other methods, you may detect your ball, calculate it's radius and even predict it's motion.

This code uses Hough Circles to compute the ball position, display it in real time and calculate it's radius in real time. I am using Qt 5.4 with OpenCV version 2.4.12

```
 void Dialog::TrackMe() {
        webcam.read(cim);         /*call read method of webcam class to take in live feed from webcam and store each frame in an OpenCV Matrice 'cim'*/

    if(cim.empty()==false)      /*if there is something stored in cim, ie the webcam is running and there is some form of input*/ {
    cv::inRange(cim,cv::Scalar(0,0,175),cv::Scalar(100,100,256),cproc);

/* if any part of cim lies between the RGB color ranges (0,0,175) and (100,100,175), store in OpenCV Matrice cproc */
    cv::HoughCircles(cproc,veccircles,CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,2,cproc.rows/4,100,50,10,100);

/* take cproc, process the output to matrice veccircles, use method [CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT][1] to process.*/

for(itcircles=veccircles.begin();   itcircles!=veccircles.end();    itcircles++)
    {
       cv::circle(cim,cv::Point((int)(*itcircles)[0],(int)(*itcircles)[1]), 3, cv::Scalar(0,255,0), CV_FILLED);    //create center point
        cv::circle(cim,cv::Point((int)(*itcircles)[0],(int)(*itcircles)[1]), (int)(*itcircles)[2], cv::Scalar(0,0,255),3);  //create circle
    }

        QImage qimgprocess((uchar*)cproc.data,cproc.cols,cproc.rows,cproc.step,QImage::Format_Indexed8);   //convert cv::Mat to Qimage
        ui->output->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimgprocess));
/*render QImage to screen*/
    }
        else
            return; /*no input, return to calling function*/

        }
```

How does the processing take place?

Once you start taking in live input of your ball, the frame captured should be able to show where the ball is. To do so, the frame captured is divided into buckets which are further divides into grids. Within each grid, an edge is detected (if it exists) and thus, a circle is detected. However, only those circles that pass through the grids that lie within the range mentioned above (in cv::Scalar) are considered. Thus, for every circle that passes through a grid that lies in the specified range, a number corresponding to that grid is incremented. This is known as voting.

Each grid then stores it's votes in an accumulator grid. Here, [2 is the accumulator ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform#Accumulator_matrix_and_voting). This means that the accumulator matrix will store only half as many values as resolution of input image cproc. After voting, we can find local maxima in the accumulator matrix. The positions of the local maxima are corresponding to the circle centers in the original space.

cproc.rows/4 is the minimum distance between centers of the detected circles.

100 and 50 are respectively the higher and lower threshold passed to the canny edge function, which basically detects edges only between the mentioned thresholds

10 and 100 are the minimum and maximum radius to be detected. Anything above or below these values will not be detected.

Now, the for loop processes each frame captured and stored in veccircles. It create a circle and a point as detected in the frame.

For the above, you may visit [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ONxIy8itRA)